# How do i find who got maximum % salary from employee table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here the emp table :
To show the employee who got the maximum % salary between 01-jan-81 and 31-dec-81

```
  EMPNO ENAME             SAL HIREDATE
------- ---------- ---------- ---------
  7369 SMITH             800 17-DEC-80
  7499 ALLEN            1600 20-FEB-81
  7521 WARD             1250 22-FEB-81
  7566 JONES            2975 02-APR-81
  7654 MARTIN           1250 28-SEP-81
  7698 BLAKE            2850 01-MAY-81
  7782 CLARK            2450 09-JUN-81
  7788 SCOTT            3000 09-DEC-82
  7839 KING             5000 17-NOV-81
  7844 TURNER           1500 08-SEP-81
  7876 ADAMS            1100 12-JAN-83
  7900 JAMES             950 03-DEC-81
  7902 FORD             3000 03-DEC-81
  7934 MILLER           1300 23-JAN-82
```

Comment: Is % salary defined as employSalary / sum(allEmpsSalary) in that period?

Comment: I guess its like ` 100/AVG(allSeleries)*SAL`. Just group by employee and define the right period. This will be the percentage salary for each employee compared to the avarage. So a 110% value would mean that this employee would have earned 10% above avarage.

Comment: Compare your personal income with other earners and find percentage

Comment: @Kirtiranjan - if so, how is maximum % salary different from maximum salary? (Are you wanting to display the % also, or just the empno and ename?) Also, what do you mean by "between 01-jan-81 and 31-dec-81"? Do you mean, who were hired between those dates? If you are going to work in the IT field, you need to be precise with your language.

Comment: @mathguy hire date is just a lengthy query or it could be optional , but i wanted to know how to calculate maximum percentage salary and this question I had faced in an interview. if you have any solution in this plz suggest the query

Comment: @Kirtiranjan - I asked for precision because your way of asking the question is confusing. (See the comments to Gordon's answer for example.) You are not answering. Did you mean "salary of employees hired between" those dates? You asked "salary between" those dates - what does that mean? Also please answer my other question: since you are only asking WHO, not HOW MUCH, why do you need to order by % and not simply by salary? What's the difference? That is exactly what I would ask the interviewer before I gave an answer.

Comment: @mathguy in between hire date who got the highest percentage salary and how much percentage will have to show

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME from EMPTABLE
WHERE
sal = (SELECT MAX(sal) from EMPTABLE where hiredate BETWEEN '01-JAN-81' and '31-DEC-81')
AND
hiredate BETWEEN '01-JAN-81' and '31-DEC-81'
```

Employee with the maximum percentage salary also has the maximum salary in the given period.

*PS: This is generic sql syntax*

Comment: This query gives wrong results - it returns employees from **any period** that got the same salary as max salary in a given period. If Tom got 100 in 1950, and Jane got max salary=100 in 1981, then the query shows Jane and Tom, but only Jane should be listed.

Comment: @kordirko Thanks for the heads up. I fixed the query!

Comment: @MiteshNinja . . . The edited answer is correct, but a bit cumbersome because you need to repeat the `where` clause twice.

Comment: i knew that query, but i want to know maximum percentage salary because i faced a query exactly on that @MiteshNinja

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to use `order by` and some sort of limit.  In Oracle 12c+, you can do:

```
select t.*
from emptable t
where hiredate between date '1981-01'01' and date '1981-12-31'
order by sal desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, you can use a subquery:

```
select x.*
from (select t.*
      from emptable t
      where hiredate between date '1981-01'01' and date '1981-12-31'
      order by sal desc
     ) x
where rownum = 1;
```

Note:  This only shows one employee.  If there are ties, an arbitrary employee is chosen.  To get all of them, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
select x.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) as seqnum
      from emptable t
      where hiredate between date '1981-01'01' and date '1981-12-31'
      order by sal desc
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at my answer? I don't feel the need to order by salary, since you can directly just find the `MAX`. Thanks!

Comment: The query gives wrong result. Imagine that SMITH was hired at 01-JAN-1981 and earns 1000 per month, while JAMES was hired at 01-DEC-1981 and earns 10.000 per month. Your query returns JAMES, but should return SMITH, because JAMES earned only 10,000, while SMITH earned 12.000 in a period from 01-JAN-81 to 31-DEC-81.

Comment: @kordirko . . . I have no reason to believe that that salary column should be pro-rated, given the information in the question.  Pro-rating is a reasonable approach -- either method is consistent with the question as currently stated.

Comment: @kordirko An extremely valid and pragmatic real-case scenario, but even that would not cover every edge case (employee leaving in between, starting in the middle of the month). So I guess we need to wait for the OP to clearly describe his problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

First we create a temp table that includes all salary of everyone in specified date and then we select the person who got the most using `max`.

```
SELECT ENAME,max(ALLSAL)
FROM (SELECT ENAME,SUM(SAL) AS ALLSAL 
    FROM t1 GROUP BY ENAME 
    WHERE hiredate between date '1981-01'01' and date '1981-12-31' ) AS t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to print % salary also

`SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT emp.*,
    round((salary/
    (SELECT SUM(salary) FROM emp
    ))*100,2) pcent
  FROM emp
  WHERE hiredate BETWEEN DATE '1981-01-01' AND DATE '1981-12-31'
  ORDER BY pcent DESC
  )
WHERE ROWNUM<=1;`

Comment: I think this 1 is correct, it helped me thanks @Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KEEP ( DENSE_RANK [FIRST|LAST] ORDER BY ... )` to get the maximum of two columns:

```
SELECT MAX( EName ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Salary ) AS EName,
       100 * MAX( Salary ) / SUM( Salary ) AS Percentage_Of_Total_Salary
FROM   Employees
WHERE  HIRE_DATE >= DATE '1981-01-01'
AND    HIRE_DATE <  DATE '1982-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
with selected_rows as (
       select empno, ename, sal
       from   scott.emp
       where  hiredate between date '1981-01-01' and date '1981-12-31'
     ),
     max_and_total_sal (max_sal, total_sal) as (
       select max(sal), sum(sal)
       from selected_rows
     )
select empno, ename, sal, to_char(100*sal/total_sal, '99.99') || '%' as percent_sal
from selected_rows cross join max_and_total_sal
where sal = max_sal;

Result:

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL PERCENT_SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
      7839 KING             5000      21.91%

1 row selected.
```

Note that the percentage is based on the sum of salaries of the employees hired in 1981 (NOT the sum of all salaries in the table). As a quick verification, clearly King has the highest salary (and therefore also the highest percentage) of all employees, and indeed he was hired in 1981, so he must be the (unique) answer to the "WHO" part of the question.

Note also that the solution depends on KNOWING that the hiredate column in the table only stores "pure dates" (that is, with the time set to 00:00:00); otherwise the "between ... and ..." part would have to be refined.